# AttributeError: /usr/lib/libgdal.so.1: undefined symbol: OGR_F_GetFieldAsInteger64

Tags: cloud, django

I am getting the error `AttributeError: /usr/lib/libgdal.so.1: undefined symbol: OGR_F_GetFieldAsInteger64` when I try to deploy Django project on google cloud can anyone please give the
GDAL dockerfile for google cloud Django
my dockerfile

```
FROM gcr.io/google-appengine/python

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
  binutils \
  gdal-bin \
  python-gdal

# Create a virtualenv for dependencies. This isolates these packages from
    # system-level packages.
RUN virtualenv /env -p python3.7

# Setting these environment variables are the same as running
# source /env/bin/activate.
ENV VIRTUAL_ENV /env
ENV PATH /env/bin:$PATH

# Copy the application's requirements.txt and run pip to install all
# dependencies into the virtualenv.
ADD  requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r /app/requirements.txt
# Add the application source code.
ADD . /app

# Run a WSGI server to serve the application. gunicorn must be declared as
# a dependency in requirements.txt.
entrypoint gunicorn -b :$PORT tiwari.tiwari.wsgi
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding [ubuntugis-unstable](https://launchpad.net/%7Eubuntugis/+archive/ubuntu/ubuntugis-unstable)

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable

sudo apt-get update
```

and install packages from it:

```
sudo apt-get install libgdal-dev
```

As `ppa:nextgis/dev` caused me a some trouble when installing `sp package` [here](https://github.com/r-spatial/sf/issues/884#issuecomment-435916734) and seem to also cause [there](https://github.com/ropensci/MODIStsp/issues/155)